# Controller design for sinuisoidal reference signal

Tags: control, matlab, simulink

I just wanted to know what people thoughts were on a controller designed for varying the height of a magnetically levitated ball with a sinusoidal reference signal.

I have completely modelled the system, linearized it about a single operating height and designed an LQR controller that works, but what would I need to implement or do differently to be able to achieve this?

Comment: Please post a circuit. From what I understand you have a reference signal and a varying signal? The varying signal changes in order to deliver a different power to the levitation device?

Comment: What is the amplitude of the reference signal is relation to the single operating point as well as total travel of the system ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the frequency of the reference signal, using the model of the input signal (\$1\over s^2 + \omega^2\$) in your controller can help you to track it, similar to the integrators (\$\frac{1}{s}\$) needed in the control to track a step input (\$\frac{1}{s}\$) and 2 integrators (\$\frac{1}{s^2}\$) to track a ramp input (\$\frac{1}{s^2}\$) as seen in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hG7dq-51AAg